# Rails how to render page fast when have to save to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Needs:

1. Save certain parameteres to a database like request refer.
2. Render response ultra fast.

Controller Example:

```
def index
  Refer.create!(refer_page: request.refer) 
end
```

When the user requests this action it does not render ultra fast, because it first needs to write to the database.

Is it possible to write to the database later?

I have tried to setup a background job but it is also slow. What is the fastest way to store this information? In a file?

Comment: How much fast do you need this response? What is the response exactly? It may be that your problem is actually the response building. How much time does the insertion in the database takes? And to send a background job? It really shouldn't take more than some milliseconds to do either, specially to send data to a background job. Did you pass a whole Ruby object or only an id to the background job?

Comment: What's the platform?  
You can run a profiler (ala http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html#profiler) to see what's slow about this, but if that's a simple ActiveRecord create! it should not slow down your app.  If that's NOT a basic ActiveRecord create! call, you'll have to post more code and a description of your setup to get any useful suggestions.

Comment: Also notice that if you run  on Webrick, it is a slow server indeed, it's made for development purposes.

Comment: Everyone above is asking good questions.  However, if you really want to do this, you can dispatch a resque worker thread to update the database as long as you don't need the information to be current.  The dispatch should return faster than a database operation.  However, that means that database update will be asynchronous to your response and that may have other side effects for you.

Comment: im looking for the same questions too, right now i know mongodb has it fast because its async save..